# Relating a geometric limit deriving the arc length of a polar curve to a Riemann sum

Tags: integration, geometry, riemann-sum, arc-length

So recently one of my friends came to me with [this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpnKy.png)

You start with a circle of radius 1 which is divided into n subdivisions. As you go counterclockwise, you plot a point which is +(1/n) radially outward compared to the last point. So for the case n=8, you start at r=0, and then at the next subdivision, you plot the point 1/8. At the next subdivision you plot 2/8, then 3/8, and so on until you reach 1. He wanted to find the length of the curve formed as n approaches infinity

He started by looking at the triangle formed by the connected points. Let $C_{n}$ be the length of the segment formed by the connected points inside a sector. Then $\frac{k}{n}$ is the length of the segment from the center of the circle to the start point of $C_{n}$. In addition $\frac{k+1}{n}$ is the length of the segment from the center of the circle to the endpoint of $C_{n}$. Using law of cosines, $C_{n}$ can be expressed as this:
$$C_{n}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)^{2}-2\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}$$

So in a discrete case, the length of the curve for n subdivisions is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)^{2}-2\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(\frac{k+1}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}$$

Taking the limit as n approaches infinity, and by doing some factoring, the length of the continuous curve for an infinite amount of subdivisions can be written as
$$\lim_{n \to {\infty}} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{k^{2}+\left(k+1\right)^{2}-2k\left(k+1\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}$$

Which is approximately 3.38

When I first saw this sum, It made me think about Riemann sums. The idea of taking a sum up to n, and them dividing it by n and taking the limit to infinity feels very closely connected to the definition of an integral. I started looking for a way to connect this infinite sum to an integral somehow.

Finding the closed form:
Intuitively it could be figured out that the equation of the continuous curve is $r=\frac{1}{2\pi}\theta$. Using the polar curve length formula, it can be shown that the length of the continuous curve is:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}dx$$

This can be expressed as an infinite sum using the definition of an integral using a Riemann sum:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\Big( a + k\frac{b-a}{n} \Big) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t) \; dt.$$

Thus the integral is equal to:
$$\lim_{n \to {\infty}} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)^{2}+1}$$

The 2pi cancels out in the end, which makes this infinite sum look very similar to the one we derrived earlier. With a little algebra, the infinite sum derrived from the discrete case can be rewritten as:

$$\lim_{n \to {\infty}} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\left(2k^{2}+2k\right)\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\right)+1}$$

They both look very similar and they both converge experimentally to 3.38 :)

I'm tempted to assume from this equation that $\sqrt{\left(2k^{2}+2k\right)\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)\right)} = \frac{2\pi k}{n}$, but I don't think I'm allowed to do that :/. There has to be a rule stopping me from doing that. Experimentally they don't really look equal, so I hit a wall with this method.

So I guess my final question is whether there is some way to rewrite that initial infinite sum as a more easily readable Riemann sum. After that, is there some way to write that as a neat integral? Thanks!

Comment: fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Taylor expansions, for small $x$:
$$\cos x=1-\frac {x^2}2  +\mathcal O(x^4) \tag{1}$$ and
$$\sqrt{1+x+\mathcal O(x^2)}=\sqrt{1+x}+\mathcal O(x^2)\tag{2}$$
With that:
$$\begin{split}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\left(2k^{2}+2k\right)\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\right)+1} &= \frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\left(2k^{2}+2k\right)\left(\frac {2\pi^2}{n^2} +\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n^4}\right)\right)+1}\\
&=  \frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1 + \frac{4\pi^2k^2}{n^2} +\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n}\right)}\\
&=  \frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n\left (\sqrt{1 + \frac{4\pi^2k^2}{n^2}} +\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n}\right)\right)\\
&=  \left(\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1 + \frac{4\pi^2k^2}{n^2}}\right) +\mathcal O\left(\frac 1 {n}\right)\\
&\longrightarrow \int_0^1\sqrt{1+4\pi^2x^2}dx \simeq 3.38...
\end{split}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was pretty intresting. I'm not too familiar with big O notation so I have some questions about your derrivation. When your foiling out $\left(2k^{2}+2k\right)\left(\frac{2\pi^{2}}{n^{2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{4}}\right)\right)$, what happens to the $\frac{4\pi^{2}k}{n^{2}}$ term? Why does $O\left(\frac{1}{n^{4}}\right)$ change into $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$? and why does it later change to $O\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)$ when its taken out of the sum? Also how do I prove (2)? Thank you again

Comment: You should understand the "big O" notation as "is bounded by" for large $n$. For instance $\mathcal O(\frac 1 {n^4})$ means bounded by a multiple of $\frac1 {n^4}$. With that said, since $k\leq n$, we have that $\frac k {n^2}$ is bounded by $\frac 1 n$. For the term $\mathcal O(\frac 1 {n^4})$, note it's also bounded by a multiple of $\frac1 n$ for large $n$.

Comment: To prove $(2)$, factor out the $\sqrt{1+x}$ term, and apply Taylor expansions.

Answer (score 0):

Staring from @Stefan Lafon's elegant solution, we have
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+4\pi^2x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1+4 \pi ^2}+\frac{\sinh ^{-1}(2 \pi )}{4 \pi }\approx 3.3830443$$

Now, just computing
$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\left(2k^{2}+2k\right)\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\right)+1}$$ for $n=10^p$, we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_{10^p} \\
 1 & 3.8679722 \\
 2 & 3.4363000 \\
 3 & 3.3884020 \\
 4 & 3.3835805 \\
 5 & 3.3830980 \\
 6 & 3.3830497 \\
 7 & 3.3830449 \\
 8 & 3.3830444
\end{array}
\right)$$